# Qualtrics Timing isn't appearing on Survey Preview

Tags: survey, qualtrics

I'm writing a survey and I would like to measure the time it takes a participant to select a choice in a multiple-choice task. I've used a page break before the question, then I added the timing question, and finally I put another page break in. Yet, when I preview the survey, once I answer the multiple choice question, it jumps to the next multiple choice question without giving me any timing data. I've selected "show hidden questions," so I'm not sure why the timing question and data aren't appearing. Thanks for the help.

The actual part of the survey I'm talking about is formatted like this:

--Page Break--

Multiple Choice Question

Timer Question

--Page Break--

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a global setting configured to only show one question per page? (This would be in the block options or survey options menus.) If so, you cannot use timers. The way around it is to put in manual page breaks between questions.